# How to make UINavigationBar shadowImage fixed?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, calayer

I have a reversed UITableView:

```
tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi))
```

NavigationBar setup:

```
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = Assets.Colors.black.color.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
view.backgroundColor = color
```

Whenever I scroll to the bottom of my TableView (to the top when inverted), shadow disappears. I want it to be constant (like at the second screenshot).
Is it possible to make UINavigationBar shadow static regardless of TableView scrolling?

How it looks now:
[No shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jumUw.png)

How it should be:
[With shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGrh6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS15/Xcode13, there is a common problem with the navigation bar's appearance. You can read more [here](https://medium.com/@sandeep.aggarwal/upgrade-to-ios-15-8c8a076c8154#4166) and apply the fixes.

Comment: There's no problem about custom background color of navbar. The problem is a disappearing shadowImage of navbar whenever you scroll to the top of UITableView

Comment: That's why I suggest to use UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance and UINavigationBar.appearance().compactScrollEdgeAppearance = appearance as it is mentioned in the article.